# ALAsset invalid after Camera Roll changes?

Tags: objective-c, ios, alassetslibrary, alasset

I write some photos to the photo library using `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()` and at the same time I display the contents of this asset group (`ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos`) using `enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:` and friends. Sometimes the assets returned by enumerating the group become sort of “invalid”, meaning that the `defaultRepresentation` call returns `nil`, although the asset is still in memory.

I noticed that this seems to happen after the photo library gets modified by the `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()` call. Is this a documented behaviour? How can I prevent it? Reloading the assets is not a feasible option, as the user might already be somewhere deeper in the UI working with the asset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is an unfortunate, but documented behavior. For reference:

> "ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification Sent when the contents of the
>   assets library have changed from under the app that is using the data.
>   When you receive this notification, you should discard any cached
>   information and query the assets library again. You should consider
>   invalid any ALAsset, ALAssetsGroup, or ALAssetRepresentation objects
>   you are referencing after finishing processing the notification."

So what you have to do is to register an observer for `ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification`. (And there is a bug in regarding this notification on iOS 5.X, see [Open Radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/10484334).)
When you receive the notification you have to reenumerate all groups and assets. There is at the moment no other way. This is very unfortunate from a GUI perspective and we can only hope Apple improves this mechanism in the future.

Cheers,

Hendrik

Comment: unfortunately this solution is not good for iOS 9 because ALAssets are deprecated.